# model that represents a food chain, the bird to eat the bug and the bug to eat the grass w/ energy

Tags: netlogo

```
breed [ bug bugs ]
breed [ bird birds  ]
bird-own [ energy ] ;; birds energy 
bug-own [ energy ] ;; bugs energy

to setup
  ca
  grow-grass
  set-default-shape bird "bird" 
  set-default-shape bug "bug"
  create-bird 3 [
    set color 37
    setxy random-xcor random-ycor
    set energy random 10  
  ]
  create-bug 20 [
    set color green
    setxy random-xcor random-ycor
    set energy random 10
   ]
  reset-ticks
end

to go
  if not any? bugs [crt 2 ]
  grow-grass
  ask bugs  
  [ move 
    eat-grass
     reproduce
    death ]

  ask birds 
  [ move 
    eat-bugs
    reproduce
    death ]
  tick
end

to grow-grass
  ask patches [
    if pcolor = white [
      if random-float 1000 < grass-grow-rate
        [ set pcolor 57 ]
  ] ]
end

to move  
  rt random 
  lt random 
  fd 1

  set energy energy -0.5
end

to eat-grass  

  if pcolor = 57
  [ set pcolor white
    set energy energy + grass-energy ]
 end

to eat-bugs  

  if color = green
  [ set pcolor black
    set energy energy +  ]
end

to reproduce     

  if energy > birth-threshold
    [ set energy energy / 2
      hatch 1 [ fd 1 ] ]
end

to death     

  if energy < 0 [ die ]
 end
```

the birds gain energy when the they eat the bugs and the bugs gain energy when they eat the grass and they use that energy to reproduce. It won't work when i click setup I'm not sure what to do. I need to show the amount of energy they get from eating and the amount they lose from reproducing and moving around

Comment: Try giving us the error that is reported. That may help people target where to look in your code.

Answer (score 1):

There were several issues with how you defined your breeds. Also, you did not define some variables you use later on. I made some modifications and the basics are now working. Have a look at the energy variables and put in your own values (I made some up as I went). I also changed the eat-bugs proc and now you have birds that do eat the bugs. Finally, I out-commented the shapes of birds and bugs as this is not essential and you can always import them later on. For now, your breeds differ in color only, not shape.
Hope this helped!

```
breed [ bugs bug ]
breed [ birds bird  ]
birds-own [ energy ] ;; birds energy 
bugs-own [ energy ] ;; bugs energy

globals [grass-grow-rate 
         grass-energy      ;; you need to define this in the setup and use it in a procedure 
         birth-threshold]  


to setup
  ca
  grow-grass
  ;set-default-shape birds "bird" 
 ; set-default-shape bugs  "bug"
  create-birds 3 [
    set color red
    setxy random-xcor random-ycor
    set energy random 10  
  ]
  create-bugs 20 [
    set color green
    setxy random-xcor random-ycor
    set energy random 10
   ]
  reset-ticks
  set grass-grow-rate 0.5   ;; put in your values
  set birth-threshold 10    ;; ditto
end

to go
  if not any? bugs [create-bugs 2 [set color green
                                   setxy random-xcor random-ycor
                                   set energy random 10]] 
  grow-grass
  ask bugs  
  [ move 
    eat-grass
     reproduce
    death ]

  ask birds 
  [ move 
    eat-bugs
    reproduce
    death ]
  tick
end

to grow-grass
  ask patches [
    if pcolor = white [
      if random-float 1000 < grass-grow-rate
        [ set pcolor 57 ]
  ] ]
end

to move  
  rt random 100
  lt random 80
  fd 1

  set energy energy - 0.5
end

to eat-grass  

  if pcolor = 57  ; what if the color is not 57? i.e. if another turtle already visited this patch?
  [ set pcolor white
    set energy energy + grass-energy ]
 end

to eat-bugs  
 ;suggested change for this proc: 
  if any? bugs 
   [set energy energy + 1
    ask one-of bugs [die]]
  ;if color = green
  ;[ set pcolor black
   ; set energy energy + 1 ]
end

to reproduce     

  if energy > birth-threshold
    [ set energy energy / 2
      hatch 1 [ fd 1 ] ]
end

to death     

  if energy < 0 [ die ]
 end
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out "Wolf Sheep Predation" in "Models Library" -> Biology. Under Tools -> "Turtle Shapes Editor" you might be able to find relevant shapes to replace wolves and sheep.